# The cardinality of an equivalence relation over a set

Tags: cardinals, equivalence-relations

I'm trying to prove the following statement:

> let $A$ be an infinite set, then for any equivalence relation $E$ on $A$, $ |E| = |A|$

But I'm really stuck. Trying to show a bijection from $E$ to $A$ made sense only when dealing with natural numbers, using maybe $f(x,y) = 2^x3^y$ but what do I do when these are real numbers?

Any idea on how this can be shown? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it clear what $|E|$ means?  Do you just mean the number of distinct equivalence classes?  But...what about the relation in which every two elements are equivalent?

Comment: Check the formal definition of relationship.  Now, think of the biggest that it could be.  Now think of the smallest it could be.

Comment: @lulu i mean the number of pairs in the set

Comment: $E$ is a subset of $AxA$ and includes the diagonal elements $(x,x)$ by reflexivity. It follows by basic cardinal arithmetic that $|E| = |A|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $E$ is an equivalence relation, it is reflexive in particular. Thus, you have an injection $A \hookrightarrow E$ given by $x \mapsto (x, x)$. Thus, $|A| \le |E|$.

On the other hand, by definition, $E \subset A \times A$ and thus, $|E| \le |A|^2$.

Now, since $A$ is infinite, we have $|A| = |A|^2,$ assuming the [Axiom of Choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice).
Then, by the [Schröder–Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem), we have $|E| = |A|$.

---

Note that you do indeed need the Axiom of Choice. Else, we may have an infinite set $A$ such that $|A| \neq |A \times A|.$ Then, taking $E = A \times A$ (which is indeed an equivalence relation), we get a counterexample.